# Python "class property" and "class function"

Tags: python

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "changzhi"

    @property
    def __name__(self):
        return self.name

>>> a = Test()
>>> a.__name__
>>> "changzhi"
>>> a.name
>>> "changzhi"
>>> a.__name__() 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Here are my thoughts:

1. When I run `a.__name__`, it returns "changzhi" because `__name__` is a property of `class Test(object)` which is modified by "@property".
2. When I run `a.name`, it returns "changzhi" because `name` is `a class property` which is defined by `__init__`.
3. When I run `a.__name__()`, it occurs an error because `__name__` is `a class property` ,not `a class function`
   Do all of my thoughts right ? Could someone explains to me ? And what the differences between `__name__` and `self.name`(in `__init__`) ?
   Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorating a function with `self.property` is just a fancy way of making a property. You can also do it manually like this:

```
>>> class X:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Me"
    def set_name(self, other):
        self.name = other
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name + "ABCDE"
    dynamicName = property(get_name, set_name)


>>> inst = X()
>>> inst.dynamicName
'MeABCDE'
>>> inst.dynamicName = "You"
>>> inst.dynamicName
'YouABCDE'
```

Note that `dynamicName` is a property, not a function. Well, it's just a syntatic sugar. Now, let's move on to your question. We can do this by using the `@property` decorator:

```
>>> class Y:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Me"
    @property
    def dynamicName(self):
        #This would be the getter function
        return self.name + "ABCDE"
    @dynamicName.setter
    def set_name(self):
        self.name = other


>>> inst = Y()
>>> inst.dynamicName
'MeABCDE'
```

In the snippet above, `dynamicName` is decorated by the `property` function. But, result of this decoration is not a function, but an attribute! This leads to your confusion.

You can simply test it:

```
>>> type(inst.dynamicName)
<class 'str'>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The type of `inst.dynamicName` is `<class 'str'>` because it is modified by `@property`. Does it right?

Comment: You can learn more about decorators [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/2106009). Actually, when you decorate a function `a` with `@b`, you're just calling `b(a)`. The returned attribute depends on the `b` function.